# Help calculating grade percentage with different categories?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know this may sound stupid but I need help calculating my grade, I'll show what I've done but I think it is wrong. The question is: What grade do I need on the final to get at least a $90\%$ in the class

Here is the guidlines:

> Programs: $50\%$
>
> Midterm: $20\%$
>
> Final: $30\%$

In Programs I have $53\%$ (yay extra credit!)

In the Midterm I have $19.4\%$

What grade do I need on the final to get at least a $90\%$ in the class

Programs + Midterm + Final = $90\%$

$53\% + 19.4\%+ Final = 90$

$Final = 17.6\%$

So I need to get $17.6\%$ out of the final to get an A? If I wanted to see what score out of $100$ points I would need to get $17.6\%$ out of $30\%$ how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I need to get $17.6\%$ out of the final (which is worth $30\%$) to get an A?

Yes.

---

To see what score you need out $100$ points if you want $17.6\%$ out of $30\%$ solve $$\frac{17.6}{30}=\frac{x}{100}$$

Comment: 58.6/100 points needed That's awesome :D. Thanks